# Does + in front of a variable in ruby ever do anything?

Tags: ruby

```
foo = 1
p +foo
```

This example code prints `1` just like if the `+` was not there. I know `-` in front of a variable gets the opposite of what the variable was (-29 becomes 29) but is there any case where a variable with a + in front of it ever does anything or can I safely remove it every time I see it? To clarify this a bit I am asking no specifically about numbers assigned to variables but any datatype in ruby.

Comment: Is this your exact example from your codebase? Like, it really just sets a variable equal to a value and then prints + variable?

Comment: I partially ask because you can define the + method on an object. So if it said bar + foo, then you may want to find out if bar has a + method that actually mutates bar with the value of foo.

Comment: @Nate It was a + in front of a string variable which seemed to do nothing

Comment: Are you asking `+` in front of numbers, or `+` in front of an object in general? It is not clear. And the answer to the question greatly differs depending on which question you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any case where a variable with a + in front of it ever does anything

Yes. Every time. It calls the `+@` method.

> or can I safely remove it every time I see it?

No, you can't. It will change the semantics of your code: before, it will call the `+@` method, after, it won't.

Whether or not that changes the outcome of your program, depends on what that method is doing. The default implementation for [`Numeric#+@`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-2B-40) simply returns `self`, but of course someone could have monkey-patched it to do something different.

Also, [`String#+@`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-2B-40) does something more interesting: if `self` is a frozen string, it will return an unfrozen, mutable copy; if `self` is already mutable, it returns `self`.

Other objects in the core library don't have a `+@` method, so they will usually raise a `NoMethodError`. If you remove the call, they won't; that is also a behavioral change.

Answer (score 6):

`+` is both a unary operator (one argument) and a binary operator (two arguments). It is defined on the `Numeric` class. [Unary operators](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Numeric.html#method-i-2B-40) are defined using `@` suffix to differentiate from the binary operator.

> Unary Plus—Returns the receiver.

This is the [source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c6ef5bc31e547ee905e5a218d293fef61647f65c/numeric.c#L533) for the method:

```
num_uplus(VALUE num)
{
    return num;
}
```

So to answer your question,

> Does + in front of a variable in ruby ever do anything?

NO, for `Numeric` values.

Answer (score 4):

I just [looked it up](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c6ef5bc31e547ee905e5a218d293fef61647f65c/string.c#L2605) for strings and yes it does do something for frozen strings.

> If the string is frozen, then return duplicated mutable string.
>
> If the string is not frozen, then return the string itself.

```
static VALUE
str_uplus(VALUE str)
{
    if (OBJ_FROZEN(str)) {
    return rb_str_dup(str);
    }
    else {
    return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, now that you say it, I totally remember reading that in the comments of this article. https://www.mikeperham.com/2018/02/28/ruby-optimization-with-one-magic-comment/

Comment: What your answer says is not false, but is totally irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @sawa Is it? I found a case where the + does something which is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Qwertie Please confer my comment to your question.